# Gnome's Files application in Ubuntu 20.04 does not properly show the thumbnail of raster image files at times

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, icons, thumbnails

I noticed that the `Files` application in Ubuntu 20.04 does not properly show the thumbnail of raster image files at times. Instead of showing the thumbnail of the image, either a white icon with a clock face or an image file icon is used to represent raster image files.
[image: Files no thumbnail issue]

To get `Files` to show the thumbnail of the image, I have to double-click on an image to activate the `Image Viewer` application. I then have to click the right arrow keys to scroll through the images. Finally, I have to use the `GIMP` application to open the most recent image that I had viewed in the `Image Viewer` application. After closing GIMP, I noticed that most/all of the files that I had scrolled through using the `Image Viewer` application will show the thumbnail of the raster image files instead of showing the image icon. These procedures need not be repeated for the same batch of image files. Files somehow remembers that they are image files and will show their thumbnail instead of using an image icon to show the raster image file.

This issue makes it difficult to browse many image files in a folder/directory. These procedures although they work are quite tedious to perform. My previous use of Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 did not give me this issue.

How do I fix this issue in the Gnome `File` application?

Comment: I have a quite similar issue with Nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04.3 and I confirm that the procedure you described (image viewer + gimp) works. The question is then, what does that change and where so that the thumbnails are generated?

Comment: As an alternative you could browse your photos with [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb) `sudo apt install gthumb`